# I need help copying data from a table in LibreOffice Base to Calc

Tags: libreoffice, clipboard

I am copying the data in a Base table and pasting it into a Calc spreadsheet.  This should just work, but I when I do it, each column from the table is spanning three columns in the spreadsheet.

I think it may have something to do with having Memo (longvarchar) fields in the table.

How can I stop this happening?

By the way, there are other format problems.  Sometimes all data is formatted with strikethrough and underline, but I can sort that out by reformatting cells.

Comment: On examining the spreadsheet further, only the first 35 data items span 3 columns each, taking up the first 105 spreadsheet columns from A to DA. Then from columns DB to DU there are a further 10 data items spanning 2 columns each. The other 81 data items are correctly allocated 1 column each, taking columns DV to GX.

If correctly allocated the 126 data items take up columns A to DV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have logged a bug for this see [this link](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51918)